# ajax progress Indicator remains executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, busyindicator

I am using ASP.NET MVC with jquery and ajax.

I have one theme where it has in built ajax processing bar / indicator for processing show.

In local I have used it is running fine and stop executing after successfully call but at client's end it remains executing still after successfully call done.

PC configuration same and browser configuration also same don't know what I left to do?

Can anyone have this kind of issue and solved it?

Don't know how to solve this!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Generally this happens because of **console errors of javascript**. If your console is clean then you can check ajax state **$.ajax.readyState** property. You can see a sample code here. Here we can cancel ajax request manually before 10 seconds (timer) of ajax call is completed [https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/cc2ck9uc/](https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/cc2ck9uc/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your console?
There must be some error generated in console due to which the ajax response is not getting completed.

Comment: No error ajax response got it correctly that's the issue I am facing now there is no error nothing but still it remains executing.

Comment: can i have url?

Comment: No it is local project

Comment: I haven't down voted @MominIqbal and yes I have checked there is no any error as well and ajax response is also completed successfully.

Comment: @3rules No issue :). and i am not pointing you :) Those are one who have a mindset to downgrade  others profile..

Comment: Ok so do you have any idea except given answer